# Is $\epsilon _{X_i}(I_n) $ an other notation for the indicator function?

Tags: notation

My book uses both of the functions $\epsilon _{X_i}(I_n)$ and $1_{X_i\in I_n}$ once with an equality sign, otherwise just the first one. Is this different notation for the same function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your book uses two different notations consistently throughout, it is possible they are different objects.

Comment: Yes that is my suspicion, but I have only seen the common notation for the indicator function once, so no real consistency. Don't know if the author was trying to be extra clear there.

Comment: Cannot you trace the definitions back in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the answer myselft, he use it to denote the discrete measure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure

$$\epsilon _{X_n}(A)=\{_{0, if X_n \setminus A}^{1, if X_n \in A}$$
.

Comment: ...While the rest of the world would probably use $\delta_{X_n}$ to denote this Dirac measure.